# What is the backstory of the display armor in the background of the yacht scene?

Tags: star-wars, props, solo-a-star-wars-story

Does anyone know the backstory of the display armor in the background in the yacht scene that looks very much like Jango Fett's helmet and possibly armor as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dryden Vos is a collector of some sorts as there are other objects in the same room as the armor.

The armor itself is a "Mandalorian rally master armor" from the Old-Republic-era.

> [image: Mandalorian armor]
>
> **Mandalorian armor.** A near-complete set of Old Republic-era ancient Mandalorian rally master armor is the centerpiece on a table of other antique weaponry.
>
> <sub>[Star Wars, 4 Amazing Easter Eggs From Dryden Vos’ Study](https://www.starwars.com/news/4-amazing-easter-eggs-from-dryden-vos-study%5D)</sub>